# clBuildProgram passes user data to kernel

Tags: opencl

I would like to use clBuildProgram to a program executable from the program source.

Is it possible to use `clBuildProgram` to pass arguments using `void *user_data` ?

```
cl_int clBuildProgram ( cl_program program,
    cl_uint num_devices,
    const cl_device_id *device_list,
    const char *options,
    void (*pfn_notify)(cl_program, void *user_data),
    void *user_data)
```

How to pass user data to kernel using clBuildProgram ?

Answer (score 2):

`user_data` is used only with `pfn_notify` and not for passing data to a kernel. To pass data to a kernel use a buffer and pass the `cl_mem` object to the kernel.

Edit: Alternatively, fixed (not changing for entire use of kernel) data could be passed using `options` and `-D name=definition` syntax, as a pre-defined macro that your kernel code could use.